# A Spaced Entry On A User Input Write to file form

Tags: php, html

I Have a code When a user types a sentence and presses add text button 
Then text gets sent to a file.

Here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Write to a text file</title>
</head>
<body>

Put Cataline/page.txt furni info, 
<form action="" method='post'>
<input name='textblock'></input>
<input type='submit' value='Add text'>
</form>

<?php

// Open the text file
$f = fopen("textfile.txt", "a");

// Write text
fwrite($f, $_POST["textblock"]); 

// Close the text file
fclose($f);

// Open file for reading, and read the line
$f = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");

// Read text
echo fgets($f); 
fclose($f);

?>

</body>

</html>
```

It works Fine. There is one issue.

I will use a example to show it.

User1: Oo i can upload my furnidata here ok ill do that *enters furnidata* T
(User1's furnidata (the text he wants added) gets sent to the file..) (it works)

Now user2 comes along

User2: My turn to add furni data (does the same as user1 and it uploads to the file and works fine

But

this is what the code looks like

`user1furnidatatatatblahblahblahendofdatauser2furnidatablahblahblahendofdata`

This is what I want it to look like

`user1furnidatatatatblahblahblahendofdata

user2furnidatablahblahblahendofdata`

Can anyone suggest me to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

**PHP/HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Write to a text file</title>
</head>
<body>

Put Cataline/page.txt furni info,
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="text"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add text">
</form>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $f = fopen("textfile.txt", "a+");
$input = "$_POST[text]\n";
fwrite($f, $input);
}
?>

</body>

</html>
```

**Output WITH ENTERS:**

```
looooooooooool
looooooooooool
looooooooooool
looooooooooool
```

**Works for me if this worked please like my answer!**

Comment: Thanks tredged your a legend i would rep you if i could, but i can not due to the fact that i am a new user

Comment: can you rep my post now? you have sufficient rep I upvoted also. Thankyou.

Comment: reped please any my question i am about to post

Answer (score 1):

Could this maybe work by adding *\r\n* after each user's "furni data"? That will most probably create a new line.

`fwrite($f, $_POST["textblock"] . "\r\n");`

Comment: it made a 2 space gap like line1:djdjdjdj line3: badjdj.. if you undersand i only need a 1space gap

Answer (score -1):

Just make a new line after each post, that aint so hard?

Comment: wouldnt the users have to do that,  the users would not know that becuase they are a bit newbie